# Installing plugins in JetBrains Fleet

Tags: jetbrains-ide, jetbrains-fleet

Hey guys I was trying out Fleet and really liked it but I had a hard time configuring it. I wanted to install a plugin but I couldn't find an option to add plugin anywhere.

Does anyone know how to install plugins in JetBrains Fleet?

Comment: Great question.. I'm really eager to find out new features in fleet, but without some extensions like todo tree or so on that I have in VS Code, I cannot work efficiently. So I guess I will wait for that

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/FL-12965/Support-custom-language-servers-LSP

Answer (score 19):

> I wanted to install a plugin but I couldn't find an option to add plugin anywhere.

That's because Fleet does not support custom (non-bundled) plugins yet (as of **October 2022**).

https://www.jetbrains.com/fleet/

[image]

> **Does Fleet support plugins?**
>
> Fleet will have its own extensibility model, and we are also looking into the option of re-using existing IntelliJ-platform plugins for Fleet. **We will provide more information about these extensibility options at a later date.**

https://blog.jetbrains.com/fleet/2022/10/introducing-the-fleet-public-preview/

> At the same time, we’re working in the following areas:
>
> - **API support and an SDK for plugin authors** – Given that Fleet has a distributed architecture, we need to work on simplifying the approach for plugin authors. While we guarantee that we’ll be providing a platform for extending Fleet, **we do ask for a bit more patience in this area.**

Answer (score 7):

With latest fleet preview, you could install plugins manually, e.g., use the famous vim plugin for fleet as an example:

1. Download the latest zip from [here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/20568-fleetvim/versions#tabs)
2. Unzip the download file
3. Copy the unzipped folder to the plugin folder of JetBrains fleet app, I installed the latest fleet preview by JetBrains toolbox, and the `cp` command would be:

```bash
cp -af ~/path/to/download/fleet.fleetVim-1.13.95 "~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/Fleet/ch-1/1.13.92/Fleet.app/Contents/Frameworks/FleetBackend 2023.1 EAP.app/Contents/plugins/"
```

- Locations of plugin directories can be found [here](https://fleet-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/7648059182226-Changing-application-configuration-caches-plugins-directories)

4. Restart the fleet app and choose `Enable vim emulation` from the `General` tab of the fleet app preference

[image: Click here for the screenshot of enabling vim emulation from preference]

Comment: Where is path plugin on linux user ?

Comment: @PamungkasJayuda  Take a look at https://fleet-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/7648059182226-Changing-application-configuration-caches-plugins-directories

Answer (score 3):

Fleet doesn't support plugins yet. The release will be announced in the  [the blog post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/fleet/) and on [twitter](https://twitter.com/JetBrains_Fleet).

Answer (score 2):

There's no information on how to install it, but I notice that the Svelte plugin claims to be Fleet compatible:

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/20504-svelte/

[image]

Comment: so Fleet will use Java for plugin development.

Comment: Do you know how to install this? I am confused because I didn't think Fleet required Java at all

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused about this as well.  But at least Fleet 1.12 now supports Svelte which is what I care about! :-)

Comment: Alright, so you know that Fleet is supported, but did you make it work ?

Answer (score 0):

Fleet doesn't support plugins yet. [JetBrain Fleet page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCYij.png)

Sorry, screenshot is in French

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33480878)