# Can't install plugins on Jetbrains Fleet 1.18.88

Tags: jetbrains-fleet

It seems like the answers in this question are out of date [Installing plugins in JetBrains Fleet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74070390/installing-plugins-in-jetbrains-fleet)

I have scoured the Fleet directory (`/home/<user>/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/Fleet/ch-0/1.18.88`) on my Fedora 36 machine, but there doesn't seem to be any plugins folder.

Does anyone know how I can install plugins like this? https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/20504-svelte

The [1.18 blogpost](https://blog.jetbrains.com/fleet/2023/05/fleet-preview-update-1-18-is-out-with-prettier-on-save-net-unit-testing-in-tree-test-rerun-safe-quitting-updated-debug-console-git-integration-improvements-and-more/) mentions the following, but I can't find it anywhere

> A list of installed (bundled) plugins is now available; therefore, it
> became much easier to discover the technologies that are used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does anyone know how I can install plugins like this?

This plugin is already bundled with Fleet. You can see the bundled plugins (but cannot install any plugins yet) in Fleet:

[image]

[image]